# Cloudformation YAML file to take script parameter as input

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am not sure whether I can utilise the parameter value as below. where am I going wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

$stack_name="IAM-IA-Account"
$username=$1

aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name $stack_name --parameters ParameterKey=Username,ParameterValue=$username --capabilities CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM --template-body file://cloudformation/setup-iam.yaml
```

when I run the bash script I get the below error

```
mXXXXXXXX@MXXXX-MacBook-Pro ~ % ./ec2-setup.sh meesho **--> (Input Parameter)**
Creating Cloudformation...

*An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateStack operation: Template format error: Every Default member must be a string.*
```

- Cloudformation document

**setup-iam.yaml**

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: 'Set up the IA user.'
Parameters:
  Username:
    Type: String
    Description: New account username
    Default: !Ref ${ParameterValue}
    MinLength: '4'
    MaxLength: '512'
    ConstraintDescription: the username must be between 4 and 512 characters
  
Resources:
  iaaccount:
    Type: AWS::IAM::User
    Properties:
      UserName: "iaaccount"
.......
.......
.......
```

I am trying to create user name as meesho based on the input parameter and expecting the cloudformation to be created.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use any references in your Defaults. Your default value for Username must be a literal string. For example:

```
Default: newuser
```

Comment: Thanks @Marcin for your response. I always thought there will be a way do it. Since its been handled in Default it seems to be not possible. Thanks.